# Are neutral-grip pull-ups as effective as standard pull-ups?

Tags: pull-ups

Are neutral-grip pull-ups, where the palms are facing each other, easier than standard pull-ups? Are they harder? Or could neutral-grip pull-ups be a perfect alternative to standard pull-ups, as if when someone does not have a pull-up bar, for example?

Thank you.

Comment: Gauging effectiveness between two variations is hard to do, without knowing what it is you're trying to accomplish with the pullups. It seems like you're asking what the difference is between them though, am I right?

Comment: @Alec Yes. Do they work the same set of muscles in the same way?